# Apex Trigger difference in Production and Sandbox

Tags: apex, trigger

I've created a sandbox org and there appear to be some differences with production. I believe a trigger is not working like it is in production, and wonder what I am missing.

The field `request_definition__c`should be populated with the picklist value of the `col_jis_ticket_type__c` field if it's set to anything other than the value of "Incident" or if the field is blank. This is not happening in the sandbox, but is working in production

I've created a record in the `BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c` object with a name of "Generic Service". This also appears against any `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c` record I create.

Any `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c` record I create with a `col_jis_ticket_type__c`of "Request Ticket" should populate the `request_definition__c`field as "Request Ticket" but this is not happening. What am I missing?

```
//2016-06-01 Column Technologies
//To allow for dependent picklists based on the Request Definition and for   changing the Request Definition after ticket creation,
//this trigger will set the Request definition based on the 'Ticket Type'   picklist value. 

trigger COL_JIS_Set_ReqDef on BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c (before insert, before update) {
List<BMCServiceDesk__SRM_RequestDefinition__c> reqdefs = [Select Name, Id    from BMCServiceDesk__SRM_RequestDefinition__c where BMCServiceDesk__Inactive__c = false];
BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c defservice = [Select Name, Id from BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c where Name = 'Generic Service' limit 1];
// Create a map of the request definition names
Map<String,Id> reqdefmap = new Map<String,Id>();
for (BMCServiceDesk__SRM_RequestDefinition__c reqdef : reqdefs){
    reqdefmap.put(reqdef.Name, reqdef.Id);
}
for (BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c inc : Trigger.New){
    if(Trigger.Isinsert){
        if(inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDefinition__c == null && inc.COL_JIS_Ticket_Type__c != null){
          inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDefinition__c = reqdefmap.get(inc.COL_JIS_Ticket_Type__c);
           inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKBusinessService__c = defservice.Id;
        }
    }
// if the ticket type is changed to Incident this means the request definition field should be blank
    else if (Trigger.oldMap.get(inc.Id).COL_JIS_Ticket_Type__c != inc.COL_JIS_Ticket_Type__c && inc.COL_JIS_Ticket_Type__c != null){
        if (inc.COL_JIS_Ticket_Type__c != 'Incident'){
            inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDefinition__c = reqdefmap.get(inc.COL_JIS_Ticket_Type__c);
          inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKBusinessService__c = defservice.Id;}
        else {
            inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDefinition__c = null;
            inc.BMCServiceDesk__FKBusinessService__c = null;
        }

    }

}
```

}

'

Comment: One thing to check is that you only have a single "Generic Service" record as the `limit 1` may select the wrong one if there are several of them.

Comment: Please check that 'Incident' is written the same way in both production and sandbox. If it is different in sandbox then it would go inside the if and populate the definition. 

Also to me it looks like that the part: if(Trigger.isinsert) always sets the definition and that the else i sets the definition to blank is only executed when its not in an insert context. Do you maybe compare a update action on production with an insert action on sandbox?

Comment: What do your test methods say? Do they pass? What lines do they cover (will help you see what is being executed). - of course this will only help if you have properly written test methods

Comment: Please check whether the trigger is active or not.

Comment: No records where populated in the `BMCServiceDesk__SRM_RequestDefinition__c` object in the sandbox, this is why it wasn't working!